# PayPal ipn handler over TLS instead of SSL using fsockopen

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to setup a paypal IPN handler script but I am getting the error below.

```
$fp = fsockopen('tls://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

This line causes these errors below -

```
ERROR - 2016-04-29 18:29:30 --> Severity: Warning --> fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure /mypaypalipn.php 988
ERROR - 2016-04-29 18:29:30 --> Severity: Warning --> fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto /mypaypalipn.php 988
ERROR - 2016-04-29 18:29:30 --> Severity: Warning --> fsockopen(): unable to connect to tls://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443 (Unknown error) /mypaypalipn.php 988
```

I tried to search here on the stackoverflow and understand that its the SSL version causing this issue and the solution is like change

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
```

But I am not using cURL. What do I do to get it working with `fsockopen`?

These are from phpinfo -

Registered Stream Socket Transports

```
tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls

Apache/2.4.12

SSL Version:    OpenSSL/1.0.1e
```

Comment: I have just changed the code to cURL now and it is working fine now for me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot explicitly set a flag to use SSL with `fsockopen()` like in curl, you can perhaps use the SSL wrapper instead see if that works,

```
 fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30)
```

Comment: Yes I tried that already - it used to work in the past but Paypal is forcing to tls now for security reasons.